# Excel VLOOKUP - Display nothing if cell is empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using the `VLOOKUP` function and I have this function   `=VLOOKUP(B9,Products!A5:K29,11,FALSE)`

It works but what do I need to add so the cell will display nothing if B9 is nothing? At the moment if B9 is nothing it displays "#N/A".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surround the whole thing with an `if` statement thus:

```
=IF(B9="","",VLOOKUP(B9,Products!A5:K29,11,FALSE))
```

with any suitable changes to the `B9=""` condition.

That way it gives you `""` if `B9` is `""` otherwise it gives you the result of the lookup.

Comment: Oh thank you, I didnt realize that you can use other functions within a function.

Comment: @jay: yes, in my early days (before I knew about things like lookups), you used to find monstrosities in my spreadsheets like `=if(b1="", if(b2="", if(b3="", if(b4="", if(b5="", "?", b5), b4), b3), b2), b1)` :-)

Comment: Haha I see. Hey man I applied this formula to every cell in the column but how do I make A5:K29 default? It changes as you down the column.

Comment: @jay, you need to make the range non-relative, something like: `$A$5:$K$29`. That will lock the values no matter where you move or copy the formula to (you can also independently set row and column non-relative but you probably don't need that in this case).

Comment: Jay, use absolute references, ie `=IF(B9="","",VLOOKUP(B9,Products!$A$5:$K$29,11,FALSE))` [dang, damn this doubling up]

Comment: I never can understand why people use "A1" mode in Excel, isn't "R1C1" mode much easier to read and visually check formulas? `=IF(RC[1]="","",VLOOKUP(RC[1],Products!R5C1:R29C11,11,FALSE))`

Answer (score 2):

For your question as asked

`=IF(B9="","",VLOOKUP(B9,Products!A5:K29,11,FALSE))`

Going a step further in case your value in B9 does not exist in your lookup range
`=IF(B9="","",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B9,Products!A5:K29,11,FALSE)),"Not found",VLOOKUP(B9,Products!A5:K29,11,FALSE)))`

Useful reference. Patrick Matthews (MVP Excel), [Six Reasons Why Your VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP Formula Does Not Work](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2637-Six-Reasons-Why-Your-VLOOKUP-or-HLOOKUP-Formula-Does-Not-Work.html?sfQueryTermInfo=1+30+vlookup)

*[The other post wasn't flagged to me at the time when I posted, that said I do recommend the additional ISNA test that I added]*